# "An invalid or illegal selector was specified" when scraping dynamic content

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape prices from this web page

I first start using Beautifulsoup then I switched to Selenium because it's dynamic data and I'm finally blocked in this:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
url = "https://cnft.tools/claynation"

s = Service(r"C:\Users\marti\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s) 

driver.get(url)

pieces = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '[name="card cardtools zoom card-group"]')
# driver.find_elements(By.XPATH('//*[@id="__next"]/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/div'))

# pieces

# for piece in pieces:
#     rank = piece.find_element("xpath", './/*[@id="__next"]/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/div').text
#     price = piece.find_element("xpath",'.//*[@id="__next"]/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div').text
#     print(rank, price)
```

and return this

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.102)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00B378B3+2193587]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AD0681+1771137]
    Ordinal0 [0x009E41A8+803240]
    Ordinal0 [0x009E6BB4+814004]
    Ordinal0 [0x009E6A72+813682]
    Ordinal0 [0x009E6D00+814336]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A121B5+991669]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A1273B+993083]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A3F7C2+1177538]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A2D7F4+1103860]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A3DAE2+1170146]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A2D5C6+1103302]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A077E0+948192]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A086E6+952038]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DE0CB2+2738370]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DD21B8+2678216]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BC17AA+512954]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BC0856+509030]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AD743B+1799227]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ADBB68+1817448]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ADBC55+1817685]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AE5230+1856048]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x765B6739+25]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x777590AF+1215]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x7775907D+1165]
```

Maybe it's because of authorisation?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not because of authorization. Error message is quite straightforward:  your selector is invalid cause you pass CSS-selector to search by Class name.

You need to replace

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '[name="card cardtools zoom card-group"]')
```

with

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="card cardtools zoom card-group"]')
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.card.cardtools.zoom.card-group')
```

Also. If you want to get *list of elements* instead of *single element* you need to use `find_elements` instead of `find_element`

Answer (score 0):

#### this is working

```
try:
    list_of_div = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='card cardtools zoom card-group']")))
    for i in list_of_div:
        print(i.text, '\n')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

You need to learn how to make Xpath.

This is a website "https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html"